# string.Trim() in Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, trim

How do I trim the Keys and Values of a Dictionary?

```
var Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Dictionary.Add("String1 ", " String");
Dictionary.Add(" String2 ", " String ");
Dictionary.Add("  String3  ", " String   ");

foreach (var KeyValuePair in Dictionary)
{
    KeyValuePair.Key.Trim();
    KeyValuePair.Value.Trim();
}
```

Does not seem to have any impact whatsoever.

Comment: Most string functions return a value and don't modify anything.

Comment: Of course not. Why dont you trim on insert if that is the aim?

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Nevermind the fact that you dealing with a valuetype and trying to 'modify' an enumeration at the same time ;p

Comment: String are immutable, they will not change this way, you will have to set them.

Comment: `Trim()` does not modify the string you call it on it returns a trimmer string. Also you cannot modify the Key of a dictionary, you should probably trim the data before adding it to the dictionary.

Comment: Well, that was a double fail :D So what I actually wanted to do was      `KeyValuePair.Key = KeyValuePair.Key.Trim();`, which doesn't work either, because they are read-only while iterating in a foreach. Thanks for clarification!

Comment: @kf198 Actually KeyValuePair.Key is read-only regardless of whether you are iterating in a `foreach` or not.  `KeyValuePair<K,V>` is an immutable class that `Dictionary` uses to expose the key-value when iterating.  But when you are in a `foreach` you cannot update a collection, so in your case you cannot call `Remove` or `Add` on the `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Trim` returns a new `string`, you need to assign it back. But you can't change the dictionary while iterating.Instead you can create a new dictionary with trimmed keys and values:

```
var newDictionary = Dictionary.ToDictionary(x => x.Key.Trim(), x => x.Value.Trim());
```

Comment: Be aware that this could throw a duplicate key exception if you have keys that differ only by the whitespace

Answer (score -3):

Strings are immutable, operations on them never change the string values.

You want to do something like this:

```
  var trimmedKey = KeyValuePair.Key.Trim();
```

Besides that, you will want to remove the item and re-add it.

```
foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
  dict.Remove(kvp.Key)
  dict.Add(kvp.Key.Trim(), kvp.Value.Trim());
}
```

Comment: You cannot modify a collection inside a `foreach`.  It will result in a `InvalidOperationException`.